# How do I build only certain submodules on the Maven multimodule?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jar, jvm, multi-module

I've configured a Maven multi-module. There is a parent module at the top, and the common, child, and friend modules were created as submodules.

And the child module and the friend module depend on the common module.

There was a change in the child module, so I wanted to build only the child module. So I ran the
`mvn clean package-pl child` build command in the directory where the pom.xml file of the parent module is located, and an error occurred as shown below.

```
$ mvn clean package -pl child
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< com.example:child >--------------------------
[INFO] Building child 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.example:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.269 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-23T23:17:32+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project child: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example:child:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example:common:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

After that, I added the `-am` option to run the `mvn clean package -pl child -am` build command and it worked fine, but the common module on which the child module depends was also built.

```
[INFO] Building jar: D:\workspace\sts\parent\child\target\child-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for parent 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.171 s]
[INFO] common ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.924 s]
[INFO] child .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.061 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.276 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-23T23:18:13+09:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm worried about is that there is a possibility that the friend module, another module that relies on the common module, may not run normally.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696970/what-happens-if-i-delete-the-xx-jar-file-after-i-started-to-execute-the-xx-jar) what's mentioned here, it says that deleting the jar file after running the app may not work properly. (The app runs on Unix os.)

Therefore, even if there is no change in the friend module or common module, if the common module is built due to the child module, the friend module that is already running will not operate normally.

What should I do? If I summarize what I want,

1. I want to build only submodules with changes.
2. If a module (such as a common module) referenced by another module changes, I want to build all of the module (child, friend) modules referenced by that module.
   (In this situation, if you give me the -amd option, I think I can solve it easily.)

I gave the mvn option and implemented it, but it was different from what I expected

Answer (score 0):

When you build with `package`, the next build will not find the already built artifacts.

To get around this, instead use the `install` goal, to make the artifact locally available for later use.